# Align objective function in latex

Tags: spacing, align

I am writing the following optimization model:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Min}{min}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&Q_t(v_{t-1},a_{ti\omega}) = \notag \\ 
&\min_{\substack{g_t,~y_t,f_t,~\theta_t,~\\\Delta u^{up},~\Delta u^{dn},\\\Delta g^{up},~\Delta g^{dn},\\g_t^c,~y_t^c,~f_t^c,~\theta_t^c}} c^\top_{t}g_{t,i}+\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^T}(c^{U}_i \Delta g^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta g^{dn}_{t,i})+ \notag \\
&\hspace{19mm}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^H}(c^{U}_i \Delta u^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta u^{dn}_{t,i})+\mathcal{Q}_{t+1}(v_t)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

However, I wanted both parts of the objective function to be close. I do not want that vertical space between them. Is there a way around?

[image: the model]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please turn your code into a compilable document!

Comment: as posted the example makes `! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.`

Comment: Remove the `cmex10` option for `amsmath`: it exists for compatibility with 15+ year old TeX distributions.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste mistake! 

Thanks, I'll remove the option

Comment: spacing of the `+` at the end of the first line is incorrect, and that persists in all the answers.  to fix it, enter an empty group, `{}`, after it, before the `\\ `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want `align`, you can add or remove space when breaking a line. In this case, at the second line break, replacing `\\` with `\\[-2em]` reduces the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}    
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Min}{min}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&Q_t(v_{t-1},a_{ti\omega}) = \notag \\ 
&\min_{\substack{...} c^\top_{t}g_{t,i}+\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^T}(c^{U}_i \Delta
g^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta g^{dn}_{t,i})+ \notag \\[-2em] % here
&\hspace{19mm}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^H}(c^{U}_i \Delta u^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta u^{dn}_{t,i})+\mathcal{Q}_{t+1}(v_t)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works in environments other than `align`, too, in case you want to switch.

Comment: Thanks! This is a straightforward  way to solve the issue. Plus, the size the equation takes on the paper fits perfectly as I am working in a two column article.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's really a single line equation so I'd use equation not align, and then use `aligned` to wrap the subterm.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Min}{min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Q_t(v_{t-1},a_{ti\omega}) = 
\min_{
\substack{g_t,~y_t,f_t,~\theta_t,~\\\Delta u^{up},~\Delta u^{dn},\\
\Delta g^{up},~\Delta g^{dn},\\g_t^c,~y_t^c,~f_t^c,~\theta_t^c}}
c^\top_{t}g_{t,i}+{}
\begin{aligned}[t]
& \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^T}(c^{U}_i \Delta g^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta g^{dn}_{t,i})+\\
&\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^H}(c^{U}_i \Delta u^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta u^{dn}_{t,i})+\mathcal{Q}_{t+1}(v_t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

And one more solution :-), based on use of `multlined` environment from package `mathtools`:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{align}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align}
Q_t(v_{t-1},a_{ti\omega}) =     \notag  \\
   \min_{\substack{g_t,~y_t,f_t,~\theta_t,~\\
          \Delta u^{up},~\Delta u^{dn},\\
          \Delta g^{up},~\Delta g^{dn},\\
          g_t^c,~y_t^c,~f_t^c,~\theta_t^c}}
   & \begin{multlined}[t][75mm]
   c^\top_{t}g_{t,i} +         
    \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^T}(c^{U}_i 
            \Delta g^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta g^{dn}_{t,i}) + \\
    \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^H}(c^{U}_i 
            \Delta u^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta u^{dn}_{t,i})+\mathcal{Q}_{t+1}(v_t)
        \end{multlined}
\end{align}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** I just discover stupid error in my code .. the position of `\notag` is on wrong side of `\\`. Now this is corrected and numbering of equation is consequently improved.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `multline` environment instead of `align`. To reduce the spacing due to the long `\substack`, use `\smash[b]`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Min}{min}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
Q_t(v_{t-1},a_{ti\omega}) = 
\min_{\smash[b]{\substack{g_t,~y_t,f_t,~\theta_t,~\\\Delta u^{up},~\Delta u^{dn},\\\Delta g^{up},~\Delta g^{dn},\\g_t^c,~y_t^c,~f_t^c,~\theta_t^c}}} c^\top_{t}g_{t,i}+\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^T}(c^{U}_i \Delta g^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta g^{dn}_{t,i})+ \\
\hspace{19mm}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}^H}(c^{U}_i \Delta u^{up}_{t,i}+c^{D}_i \Delta u^{dn}_{t,i})+\mathcal{Q}_{t+1}(v_t)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]